# Is there a way to rotate values in a list but every 3rd position on the list is stationary?

Tags: python, list, iteration

for some homework, my teacher decided to give us a coding challenge that she couldn't work out herself. The challenge was that given a list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] rotate every second value right along the list while keeping every 3rd value stationary.

Below is the code I have tried to use but it only keeps the value at position 0 stationary, whereas I need to keep the values at positions [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

```
rotation = list(teams)       # copy the list
random.shuffle(rotation)

fixtures = []
for i in range(0, len(teams)-1):
    fixtures.append(rotation)
    rotation = [rotation[0]] + [rotation[-1]] + rotation[1:-1]
```

The expected result should be that he first iteration of the list should return [1, 12, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 10] and the second iteration should return [1, 10, 3, 12, 5, 2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 11, 8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your expected output, you need to keep every 2nd element of the list, which can be extracted by `[::2]`:

```
rotate = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
rotate[::2]
#[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

The other elements which require shuffling can be extracted by `[1::2]`:

```
rotate[1::2]
#[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Now you just need to move the last element of the 2nd list to the top. There are many ways to do it, but I got lazy and use the below:

```
result = [rotate[1::2].pop(-1)] + rotate[1::2][:-1]
```

Then you can join the amended lists together:

```
r = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(rotate[::2],result)]
r = [x for i in r for x in i]
r
#[1, 12, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If divided into subtask, then

```
import itertools

def func(array):
    const_part = array[::2] # get constant part 
    ch_part = array[1::2] # get changing part
    ch_part = ch_part[-1:] + ch_part[:-1] # items shift in changing part
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(const_part,ch_part))) # construct list back
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rotate(x):
    y = x[:]
    for i, v in enumerate(x[:-1]): 
        if str(i/2)[-1] == '0':
            x[i+1] = y[i-1] 
    return x 
x =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] 
print(rotate(x)) #[1, 12, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 10]
print(rotate(x)) #[1, 10, 3, 12, 5, 2, 7, 4, 9, 6, 11, 8]
```